# Keras autoencoder model for detect anomaly in text

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm, autoencoder

I am trying to create an autoencoder that is capable of finding anomalies in text sequences:

```
X_train_pada_seq.shape
(28840, 999)
```

I want to use a layer Embedding. Here is my model:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_len_str, ))
encoder_emb =  Embedding(input_dim=len(word_index)+1, output_dim=20, input_length=laenge_pads)(encoder_inputs)

encoder_LSTM_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(400, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))(encoder_emb)
encoder_drop = Dropout(0.2)(encoder_LSTM_1)
encoder_LSTM_2 = Bidirectional(GRU(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=False,  name = 'bottleneck'))(encoder_drop)

decoder_repeated = RepeatVector(200)(encoder_LSTM_2)
decoder_LSTM = Bidirectional(LSTM(400, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))(decoder_repeated)
decoder_drop = Dropout(0.2)(decoder_LSTM)
decoder_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(999, activation='softmax'))(decoder_drop)

autoencoder = Model(encoder_inputs, decoder_output)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
autoencoder.summary()


Model: "model_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        [(None, 999)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_19 (Embedding)     (None, 999, 20)           159660    
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 999, 800)          1347200   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 999, 800)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 400)               1202400   
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector (RepeatVector) (None, 200, 400)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirection (None, 200, 800)          2563200   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 200, 800)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_6 (TimeDist (None, 200, 999)          800199    
=================================================================
Total params: 6,072,659
Trainable params: 6,072,659
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But when training the model:

```
history = autoencoder.fit(X_train_pada_seq, X_train_pada_seq, epochs=10, batch_size=64, 
                    validation_data=(X_test_pada_seq, X_test_pada_seq))
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 999) and (None, 200, 999) are incompatible
```

How to remake the model to fix the error?

Comment: Please include your `fit` call.

Comment: Change return sequence to False on the last lstm layer.

Comment: @FariborzGhavamian if i hange return sequence to False on the last lstm layer, I get the following error: `TimeDistributed Layer should be passed an input_shape  with at least 3 dimensions, received: [None, 800]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen your code snippet and it seems that your model output need to match your target shape which is (None, 999), but your output shape is (None, 200, 999).

You need to make your output model shape match the target shape.

Try using `tf.reduce_mean` with `axis=1` (averages all the sequence):

```
decoder_drop = Dropout(0.2)(decoder_LSTM)
decoder_time = TimeDistributed(Dense(999, activation='softmax'))(decoder_drop)
decoder_output = tf.math.reduce_mean(decoder_time, axis=1)
```

This should let you fit the model.

Answer (score 0):

your last layer (output) should be of this shape

batchsize x 999 x 200) #999 words, 200 is dim of each word

Currently the output of your model is
batchsize x 200 x 999

which is incorrect.

use sparse categorical cross entropy as loss function.
then it will work.